# How to generate a bunch of lists of random numbers which have no repeats but in a certain range with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random, shuffle

I actually need to generate a bunch of lists of random numbers in the range of 1 to 5. I know how to generate a single list of random numbers in the range of 1 to 5 with shuffle module, but what if I want a bunch of such stuffs? 
I have no idea to use loop ,is there anyone can help?
Many appreciates~

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
hh = list(range(1,6))
rd.shuffle(hh)

print(hh)
```

I just want to repeat this code for 500 times 
And get an assembled output

Comment: Welcome to [so], please provide a [mcve] of your code, aswell as let us know what you've tried so far and what the expected outcome looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

f = []
for i in range(5):
    f.append(random.sample(range(5), 5))
print(f)
```

or

```
x = [random.sample(range(5), 5) for i in range(5)]
print(x)


[[3, 0, 1, 4, 2], [4, 2, 0, 3, 1], [4, 0, 1, 3, 2], [3, 0, 1, 2, 4], [4, 3, 2, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Very kind of you but I need to get 5 numbers without repeats such as[ [1,4,2,3,5],[2,4,1,5,3]]

Comment: I’d like more number list like these so I replace the ‘5’ after ‘range (5)’ to 10,but get an error...what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the Python standard library, there is [*random.sample()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) that solves the problem directly:

```
>>> from random import sample
>>> sample(range(2_400, 8_800, 100), k=10)
[6200, 7000, 3600, 7800, 6900, 5500, 4000, 7700, 5200, 2800]
```

The *sample()* function chooses values from range without replacement.

To allow repetitions (selection with replacement), use [*random.choices()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices):

```
>>> from random import choices
>>> choices(range(2_400, 8_800, 100), k=10)
[2500, 5400, 7600, 2500, 3500, 2600, 5400, 5200, 3700, 7600]
```

For *numpy* use [*numpy.random.choice()*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy.random.choice).  It has options for with or without replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy`

```
num_range = np.random.default_rng()
num_range.choice(10, size=5, replace=False)

array([7, 8, 4, 3, 0], dtype=int64)
```